# Delay network connect on bootup, or retry after X seconds

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, dd-wrt

I have a Plex Server running on my Windows 7 Dekstop and a network drive running on my DD-WRT router with all my Plex media.  When my desktop boots up, despite me telling it to remember my username and password it doesn't connect to this network path (it is NOT a mounted drive on my local PC, I access it via `\\router\path\to\drive\`).  Is it possible for me to tell my PC to try to connect again after X seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BAT file that will connect to the mapped drive Here is the syntax:

```
Option Explicit
Dim u, p, s, l
Dim Network: Set Network= CreateObject("WScript.Network")

ping 192.0.2.2 -n 8 -w 10000 > nul

l = "Z:"
s = "\\10.0.1.1\DRIVENAME"

u = "ROUTERNAME"
p = "PW"

Network.MapNetworkDrive l, s, False, u, p
```

This is using l as the drive letter you want to map, s as the path to the drive, u as the username and p as the password. The ping line will make the script wait a bit of time before trying to connect, current set to about 7 seconds. Windows takes about a second to ping so we are specifing the number of tries before it times out with the -n switch. You can adjust the time by changing the -n 8 to a different number.

You can then add this to your Local Group Policy editor by running the gpedit.exe in the run command. Then navigate to User Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts. Here is an example of what it looks like:
[image: Local Policy Editor]

You can also use Task Scheduler to do this too.

Most of this came from a post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563028/script-to-map-network-drive).